# trying to do a thread join in a method

Tags: rust

I have this code. It starts a background thread and passes work to it. I want to be able wait for the background thread to close cleanly (I know there is no way for it to stop at the moment, and I know it should be in a Drop implementation too. I am just trying to get the basic bones going)

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

pub struct S2 {
    jh: JoinHandle<()>,
    tx: Sender<i32>,
}

impl S2 {
    pub fn new() -> S2 {
        let (tx, rx): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = mpsc::channel();

        let jh = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let item = rx.recv().unwrap();
            println!("got {:?}", item)
        });
        S2 { jh, tx }
    }

    pub fn queue(&self, item: i32) {
        self.tx.send(item).expect("oops");
    }

    pub fn wait(&mut self) {
        self.jh.join().expect("oops");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s2 = S2::new();
    s2.queue(42);
    // s2.jh.join().expect("oops");
}
```

The commented out line works fine. But that exposes the implementation details to the caller. I want it in a method. But the method one wont compile.

```
   Compiling tq3 v0.1.0 (C:\work\rust\tq3)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.jh` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src\main.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         self.jh.join().expect("oops");
   |         ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.jh` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I have tried my usual guesses at satisfying rust but so far have not been able to find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` function as you define it,

```
pub fn wait(&mut self) {
     self.jh.join().expect("oops");
}
```

takes a mutable reference to an `S2`. But `JoinHandle::join` consumes the handle (it doesn't take a reference, but a value)

The key to understanding how to work around the error is to think about what state the S2 object will be in after `s2.wait()`.

If you want the object to still be valid, but the join handle it contains will no longer be valid then the type of the handle can't be `JoinHandle<()>`, but maybe `Option<JoinHandle<()>>`.

If the object is no longer valid after a call to `wait`, then you can make `wait` take `self` rather than `&mut self`.

You can see examples with both these approaches [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0aeb6758dca9b9a44b8099dd3d7f923). They really deserve better error handling, especially the S3 case - where a double call to `.wait()` should be handled better. (You can't do a double call on S2 in my version since the first call consumes your instance).

Comment: But with th e’inline’ version the s2 object is in the same ‘zombie’ state, but the compiler doesn’t complian

Comment: @pm100 I'm not sure what you mean. The compiler will complain if you try to use an `S2` object in any way after you wait on it. It doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Ah, I think you are referring to the loop never exiting... I thought that was a simplification in your code... you let the other thread know you are finished submitting work to it. One way to do that is to pass an `Option<i32>` rather than an `i32` and submit `None` as part of wait.

Comment: You can see a version using the `Option` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c33e77b99567288834190502fe956de1)

Comment: i fundamentally dont get why it makes a difference being inside a function